# Can a global element definition be overridden with a local element defintion?

Tags: xml, xsd

Is it legal to define a global element in XML schema and then override that element definition within the context of a particular parent element? Can the same element be defined both globally and locally within a schema or does it have to be one or the other?

An example of overriding a global element might look like the following. Note is defined as a global element containing several other elements. However, within the context of a book, it is an element that simply holds a string.

```
<xs:element name="note">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="to" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="from" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="heading" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="body" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="book">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="title" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="note" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you may do so. If you wish to use the global definition, you'd use `ref` instead of `name`. However, do mind that combining these two within the same sequence would not be allowed since a validator could then no longer determine which of the two you mean.

EDIT: actually, you're not really "overriding" anything. You've just made an anonymous definition of an element with name "note". It'd be overriding if you used `ref` and then changed the definition locally, but that can't be done either AFAIK. It wouldn't make sense anyway.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I also double-checked my sample schema via the on-line validator at http://www.validome.org/grammar/validate/, and confirmed that this is indeed valid.

Comment: Yeah, I just pasted it in XMLSpy and hit F8 :p Don't really know the XML Schema spec well enough to answer this right away. Sometimes I'm only as smart as my tools allow me to be.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this because you haven't overridden anything. You have one global definition and your "inner" note (within book) is a local definition that is in fact unrelated to the global note.